# I ask for help in the fight against repainting using indicators from Alex grover

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, indicator

There are 3 indicators of the same "square wave" (trend stepper) family.

1. The first has the necessary characteristics, but has repainting! They helped me fix this by adding the "lookahead" function, but this is not good, because there is a loss of fresh data and everything does not work as I wanted.
2. There are 2 almost identical indicators "Efficient Trend Step" and "Trendstep" by Alex grover (Tradingview). They have different characteristics, but most importantly, they have no repainting and they work almost without delay, it seems to me!
   And there is no "lookahead" function, which shows the ability to do without it to combat repainting.

My task is to ask you to help me combine the necessary characteristics (1) of the first indicator with the necessary feature of the lack of repainting without delay (2) of two indicators, how can this be solved? thanks

1.indiator

```
study("1 long indicator ABCSStudy",overlay=true)
long_timeframe = input(title="Long timeframe", type=resolution, defval="1440")
step_shift = input(0,"Step Shift")
ha_symbol = heikinashi(tickerid)
long_ha_close = security(ha_symbol, long_timeframe, hlc3)
long_step = ema(long_ha_close[step_shift],1)
plot(long_step,title="LongStep",color=white,linewidth=2,style=line)
```

2.indicators

```
//@version=4
study("Efficient Trend Step",overlay=true)
length = input(100),fast = input(50),slow = input(200),src = input(close)
//
er = abs(change(src,length))/sum(abs(change(src)),length)
dev = er*stdev(src*2,fast) + (1-er)*stdev(src*2,slow)
a=0.,a := src > nz(a[1],src) + dev ? src : src < nz(a[1],src) - dev ? src : nz(a[1],src)
//
css = fixnan(a > a[1] ? #2E9AFE : a < a[1] ? #e65100 : na)
plot(a,color=css,transp=0,linewidth = 3)


//@version=3
study("Trend Step",overlay=true)
length = input(50)
//
src = close
dev = stdev(src,length)*2
a = 0.
a := n < length ? src : src > nz(a[1],src) + dev ? src : src < nz(a[1],src) - dev ? src : a[1]
css = fixnan(a > a[1] ? #2196f3 : a < a[1] ? #e65100 : na)
plot(a,color=css,linewidth=2,transp=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find all the information you need on resolving these repainting issues in the descriptions of the 2 scripts: [How to avoid repainting when NOT using security()](https://www.tradingview.com/script/s8kWs84i-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-NOT-using-security/) and [How to avoid repainting when using security() - PineCoders FAQ](https://www.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/).

The [User Manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Indicator_repainting.html) also has a good text on repainting.

Comment: Thank you, you already sent this information to me in another topic and helped, but these indicators do not have the "Lookahead" function in the script and they behave perfectly except for just other characteristics ... what I do not understand?

Comment: you want to say that these indicators from Alex Grover are based on an article "How to avoid repainting when NOT using security()" ?

Comment: The **How to avoid repainting when using security() - PineCoders FAQ** indicator shows exactly how to use `lookahead` to avoid repainting when using `security()`. And no, I'm not saying that Alex's code is based on any of those examples. I'm saying that if you want to make it not repainting, you can follow the instructions mentioned in the **How to avoid repainting when NOT using security()** indicator's description, since Alex's code does not use `security()`.

Comment: how then did Alex achieve no repainting and no delay without applying one of these two articles?
How do I apply this to my 1 indicator?
sorry if I do not understand simple things, but I will solve it